# Swift не сдвигается TableView при появлении клавиатуры при нажатии на TextView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, tableview

День добрый!
У меня есть ViewController в нем TableView в таблице TextField и TextView,
я написал вот такие расширение

```
extension UIViewController {
    func registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: ((CGSize?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: { notification -> Void in
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentInset.top, left: scrollView.contentInset.left, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: scrollView.contentInset.right)

            scrollView.setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(contentInsets)
            block?(keyboardSize)
        })
    }

    func registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: ((CGSize?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: { notification -> Void in
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentInset.top, left: scrollView.contentInset.left, bottom: 0, right: scrollView.contentInset.right)

            scrollView.setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(contentInsets)
            block?(keyboardSize)
        })
    }
}

extension UIScrollView {
    func setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(_ edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.contentInset = edgeInsets
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
    }
}
```

и добавил в ViewDidLoad вот такие строчки

```
        self.registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(self.tableView)
        self.registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(self.tableView)
```

При нажатие на ячейку таблицы где TextField появляется клавиатура и таблица сдвигается вверх на высоту равную клавиатуре, а вот при нажатии на ячейку в которой TextView ничего не происходит, я не могу понять в чем причина. Есть у кого идеи?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, может поможет [Scroll UITextField above Keyboard in a UITableView OR UIScrollView in Swift](https://gist.github.com/benjaminhorner/1db43dfb6a314c6da515)